# post an email to a survey using the surveymonkey api

Tags: c#, json, curl, post, surveymonkey

we have a survey in surveymonkey and using c# to try and add the email addresses to the survey using the surveymonkey api.  the api works fine for GETS but we have yet to get a POST to work.  all we get back is

"docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes",
  "message": "There was an error retrieving the requested resource.",
  "id": "1020",
  "name": "Resource Not Found",
  "http_status_code": 404

all of the id's are correct as we can GET information about the survey but cannot POST to it.  we have granted all the scopes so there shouldn't be a limitation or restriction on that side.  SurveyMonkey api support might as well not exist as they are a complete waste of time and cannot answer a single question about their api.

the code below is our latest attempt at calling out to the api with a POST.  we put the actual ids in the uri instead of {id}  I did not include our id's here for the obvious reasons.

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
var uri = new Uri("https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/{id}/collectors/{id}/messages/{id}/recipients-d");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SurveyMonkeyAccessToken"]);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var content = new StringContent("{ \"email\": + " + emailAddress + " }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync(uri,content);
ParseSurveyPostResponses(response)
}

anyone successfully post to a surveymonkey survey using their V3 api?

Comment: Can you post the actual `Url` you are hitting? The `id=1020` may be a clue to your problem.

Comment: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes

Comment: the url for the error codes shows what there is for id 1020.  it is just a generic error and doesn't give much of a hint as to why the api craps out.  thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are using the wrong Url to post then.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to create an email collector? Are you trying to create a new message on that email collector?
 Are you trying to add recipients to that email? are you trying to send out the email?

[Creating an email collector](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-collectors):

```
POST /v3/<survey_id>/collectors
{
    "type": "email"
}
```

[Adding a message](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages) to an email collector:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages
{
    "type": "invite"
}
```

[Add recipients](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-recipients) to a message:

```
POST /collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id>/recipients
{
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Example",
    "custom_fields": {
        "1": "First Value",
        "2": "Second Value",
        "3": "Third Value"
    },
    "extra_fields": {
        "field_name1": "field_value1",
        "field_name2": "field_value2"
    }
}
```

NOTE: You can also [add recipients in bulk](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-recipients-bulk)

NOTE2: Custom fields are stored on the associated contact in your contact list, Extra Fields are only stored on the recipient for that message and only accessible through the API.

[Sending](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-send) out the email:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id>/send
{
    "scheduled_date": "2017-07-18T16:52:22"
}
```

NOTE: you can exclude the `scheduled_date` and just send in `{}` to send the message right away.

Comment: we are trying to add a recipient to an existing email collector.  once we have added the recipient then we will post a a send.  we would like to include a custom field.  you wouldn't happen to have the post call to recipients that includes the email, first and last name as well as a custom field?

Comment: thanks, i get "The body provided was not a proper JSON string" as soon as I include anything but email, first and last name..

Comment: also, as soon as I add an email to the collector it closes it.  i could create a collector for each email i send but there will be hundreds of them pretty quickly

Comment: It shouldn't close the collector, but you need a new message to invite more recipients. You can keep using the same collector.

Comment: my post string {"email": kc.604@gmail.com","first_name": "Kevin & Branda","last_name": "Collins","custom_fields": "{"1": "04900000001"},"extra_fields": "{"field_name1": ""}}

Comment: any idea why i get the error when including a custom field?

Comment: Your quotes are all messed up in the body you posted, not proper JSON

Comment: Try this:
{
    "email": "kc.604@ gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Kevin & Branda",
    "last_name": "Collins",
    "custom_fields": {
        "1": "04900000001"
    },
    "extra_fields": {
        "field_name1": "field_value1"
    }
}

Comment: Already in json stringified state:  '{"first_name": "Kevin & Branda", "last_name": "Collins", "email": "kc.604@ gmail.com", "custom_fields": {"1": "04900000001"}, "extra_fields": {"field_name1": "field_value1"}}'

Comment: @lockforward if the answer is sufficient, do you mind accepting the answer?