# Invite Recipients to Survey Monkey collector API php

Tags: php

I am trying to add multiple recipients to message in survey monkey.
this is my code:

```
$data = [
    [

        'email' => 'dsfdsfd@gmail.com',
        'first_name' => 'sdf sdfsdf',
        'custom_fields' => [
            "1" => '20-20-2020'
        ]
    ]
];

$cURLConnection = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/119550392/collectors/175336023/messages/' . $message_id . '/recipients/bulk');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth_data);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$list = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);
```

for some reason I am getting this error:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1002
            [name] => Bad Request
            [docs] => https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes
            [message] => Invalid schema in the body provided.
            [http_status_code] => 400
        )

)
```

I can't understand what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: from what I saw here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171381/post-an-email-to-a-survey-using-the-surveymonkey-api the array i build correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved the problem.
the array suppose to be with contact index before the data.

Comment: Please show what you changed so that researchers don't have to guess what you mean.