# Facing error while creating message on survey monkey

Tags: surveymonkey

I am facing this error while creating messages in survey monkey.

```
{
    "error": {
        "id": 1000,
        "name": "Bad Request",
        "docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes",
        "message": "Unable to process the request with the provided input.",
        "http_status_code": 400
    }
}

Endpoint -> https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/collectors/422848384/messages

json-body -> {
  "type": "invite"
}
```

Comment: A status 400 error stands for "bad request" so something in your request to the api endpoint is not correctly setup.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message, but also the code itself, a [mcve]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath the same endpoint I tried to get the messages from survey monkey and it worked. It seems that it has some issues with the JSON body. I have seen that answer and tried the same but it does not work in my case.
Attaching link for your reference -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171381/post-an-email-to-a-survey-using-the-surveymonkey-api

Comment: @Adriaan, I'm trying to hit that request with the postman. So how do I provide the code to debug this? There are some issues with API. I have already read that documentation and provided all the things I have. If someone have knowledge of Survey Monkey can easily get it.

Comment: @VishalChandnani Did you properly authenticate with the API?

Comment: @Psychotechnopath, yes that's why I'm saying the same endpoint is working in GET request. There is some issues with JSON I guess.